# NSFetchedController and sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a Parent Entity Person. It has two Child Entities, Man and Woman.

I want to do a NSFetchedResultsController with them sectioned by the Entity (secion 0 would be Men, section 1 would be Women).

Can I sort them by section based on which Class it is (`Man Class` vs `Women Class`? Or do I need to add an attribute stating if its Man or Woman and section by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.entity.name` will return the entity name as an `NSString`. So you could use that. I don't think it's such a great idea to have internal details (the name of an Entity) drive the UI. It's easy enough to declare an attribute for the section name, and then you have full control of the name (including localization).

Comment: I don't think that you can use `entity` or `entity.name` in the sort descriptor for the FRC, so you *have* to add an attribute.

Comment: @Log139 Did you add the attribute to the parent entity? How did you return a value in code when its not a transient attribute. 

I tried to add a transient attribute to the parent entity, I can use that as sectionNameKeyPath. But since its not allowed to use transient values in sortdescriptor, I cannot get it to work. (Since the fetchedResultsController requires me to sort the objects by section).